# Java: Can't change LowerCase to UpperCase?

Tags: java, swing, char, jtextarea

So I've got this code:

```
                    char ch = field.getText().charAt(0);
                if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
                    ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);

                }
```

And it's not working, Please help.

Comment: Come one. Read the javadoc. And google for JTextArea tutorial.

Comment: You'll find what you need : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html. To check upper/lower case of your character, go there http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: `char c = textArea.getText().charAt(0);` and `if (Character.isLowerCase(c)){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call `String str = textarea.getText();` then use `char ch = str.charAt(0)` and finally use `Character.isLowerCase(ch)`.